# ScrewTurn wiki and custom asp.net membership provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, wiki, screwturn

I'm thinking of implementing the [Screwturn Wiki](http://www.screwturn.eu/) for documenting the administration area of a website. I would like to use the existing custom asp.net membership provider so that access to the wiki is seamless. So it would look something like this:

- `http://www.example.com/admin` - Existing administrative area
- `http://www.example.com/admin/wiki` - Wiki

There's a plugin called [HTTPUserProvider Plugin](http://stcez06.kiwipad.com/Default.aspx?Page=HTTPUserProviderPlugin&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) which allows you to authenticate on another webserver through a web request, but this seems like kind of a hack.

Anybody have experience with this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have one now:

http://www.screwturn.eu/Customize.UsersPluginsV2.ashx#ASPNet_Membership_User_Provider_33

Comment: Thats probably a version 2.0 plugin. Current version is 3.x. You might want to ask around in the STW forums if anyone has updated it.

Answer (score 2):

Keltex,

A little late for you perhaps, but there is now an ASP.NET Membership provider for STW3:
http://www.screwturn.eu/Customize.ASP-NET-Membership-Proxy-User-Provider.ashx